# Updating Problem: The Black Screen

Tags: boot, 14.10

I just updated from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 14.10. When I tried booting up my computer, everything started normal, there was a purple screen, then the screen turned black.

I can access the try menus, but when I enter my name an password, it says my login is incorrect. I can't do anything from the black screen, and when try booting and using shift nothing happens. 
 
Any solutions  this problem? I really need this computer to work